# Is reasonable to have a potential satisfying these two properties?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, potential

Let $F\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}, \mathbb{R})$ satisfying the following properties:

a) there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
$$\limsup_{x\to 0} F(x) |x|\le -c<0;$$

b) $F(x)\stackrel{|x|\to\infty}{\sim} x^{1+\varepsilon}$ (I mean, $F$ is a bit faster that $x$ at infinity).

From a physical point of view, it is reasonable to have a potential (for example electric, magnetic, or other types) which behaves like described in $a)$ and $b)$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: Try compare with the Coulomb potential in 3D.

Comment: @Qmechanic The Coulomb potential clearly satisfies $a)$, but I am not sure about $b)$ because it should be $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} |\nabla F(x)|=0$. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only note that such potentials have been considered, e.g., Commun. Theor. Phys. 70 (2018) 179–184:

> With a view to generate improved results for quark-antiquark systems
> here, in the present work, we consider a general interaction potential
>
> $V(r) = a r^2 + b r −\frac{c}{r}+\frac{d}{r^2},$ (1)
>
> where a, b, c and d are positive potential parameters, which will be
> fixed by considering experimental data later on. The additional term
> $\frac{d}{r^2}$ to Cornell plus harmonic (CpH) potential improves the
> behavior of potential in the region $r\to 0$ i.e. it provides better
> confinement and leads to improved results as compared to CpH
> potential.[13]
>
> The other important interaction potentials like Cornell and Cornell
> plus harmonic potentials are special cases of potential (1). This
> potential has also been used to investigate the energy eigenvalues
> spectra of quantum dot systems [15−16] and we also successfully
> applied the same potential to calculate bound energy states of a
> number of diatomic molecules.[17]

Comment: akhmeteli, thank you for your answer. Then, that $V(r)$ can not be thought of as an electric potential, right?

Comment: @C.Bishop : I am not sure. When I looked at your question, I noted that the potential you are interested in increases with distance all the way to infinity, so I thought that it could only describe some kind of confinement, e.g., it could be something like interquark potential. However, the article I quoted also mentions quantum dots and diatomic molecules, so it could also be something besides strong interactions.